# How do I find the word 'error ' in which folder it is in Unix?

Tags: unix

I am trying to find a word ''Error'' in the log file. But I do not know in which folder it is. Will `ls-lr | Grep ''Error''` work?

Comment: This is not about programming. Moreover, you can be expected to do a little research yourself, like reading one or two man pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the below to find the files with the word Error

```
grep -R Error  <directory path>
```

Comment: Hi Djo 

If I do not know the path and want to know in which directory it is then what shall be the command

Comment: grep -R Error / 
this will scan the entire filesystem